# Getting relative path javaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, relative-path

Im trying to get a relative path of my location to another.
My folder tree looks like that: /server/modules/training/barakg/a
                                /server/build/Prod.xml

Im in folder a, and I need to get a relative path from my folder to the file Prod.xml. 
Could someone show me an example how to build the relative path from my source folder to the destination file? I need it to be dynamic, to get always the relative path to Prod.xml file. I need it to be in javascript

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: 
https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/path.html#path.relative

for your example, you can try:

```
path.relative(process.cwd(), '/server/modules/training/barakg/a/server/build/Prod.xml')
```